# Black screen after sleep with only mouse displaying on 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, mouse, display, suspend

I'm very new to linux, we recently switched from Windows to it at work. I'm having an issue that if I lock the screen or just leave my computer idol for awhile, the screen eventually goes black, but then when I try to resume working on it, it only displays a black screen with the mouse cursor on it. This means I'm having to constantly restart my machine every single time this happens.

I seen similar questions to this when googling for solutions, but they seem to be either be for when you initially start the machine, or a different version of Ubuntu, or for XUbuntu. Some tell me to restart gnome...which I don't even think my machine has.

If anyone can offer me any help, that would be great.

Some of my tower specs:

Memory: 32GB RAM

Processor: Intel Core i5-6500 CPU @ 3.20GHz x 4

Graphics: NVIDIA Gefore GT710 (as far as I know)

OS: 64bit

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this exact problem the other day after I installed graphics card on to my Ubuntu 16.04 system. I tried all of the things suggested in those other forum posts but in the end the only thing which actually solved the problem was a fresh install of the operating system...

I'm not sure if that would help you but it worked for me.

Comment: Yeah after searching for solutions, it does seem like it's related to the graphics card. I would do a fresh install, but only for the fact that it took a long time to get my development environment set up, and I'd have to go through all that again if I reinstall the OS.